# React, redux. DOM updates, but no reflow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dom-events, cesiumjs

My code is in React. So, in one component, say, AppViewerEvents I am handling a mouseMove event inside a canvas. It takes current mouse pointer coordinates on canvas and dispatches a redux action, which simply updates `coordinates` object with new values.

```
<ScreenSpaceEvent
                    type={Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE}
                    action={(e: CesiumMovementEvent) => {
                        const position = scene?.pickPosition(e.endPosition!);
                        if (position) {
                            const cartographic = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(position);
                            const longitude = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude);
                            const latitude = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude);
                            dispatch(setCoordinates({ longitude, latitude, elevation: cartographic.height }));
                        }
                    }}
                />
```

This action is handled by reducer blazingly fast each time, so redux isn't the problem.
In the other component, CoordinatesBar, I'm subscribing to this piece of store by useSelector and rendering this coordinates in JSX like so:

```
                    const { coordinates } = useSelector(state => state.projectView);
...

                    <div className='coord'>
                        <span className='spacer'>
                            {${coordinates.longitude?.toFixed(numberOfDigits)}° N`}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='line' />
                    <div className='coord'>
                        <span className='spacer'>
                            {${coordinates.latitude?.toFixed(numberOfDigits)}° E`}
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

And the problem is: if I inspect my page in devtools element picker, i can see DOM updating (span value changing) each time the event is firing, and action dispatched, as expected. But I don't see the 'repainting' or reflowing on the page itself. It only occures, once I stop moving the mouse and firing events. Moreover, this isn't the case in Firefox, only in Chrome.
Help, please, I've been googling for 3 days, and nothing.